# How can I find the code that's refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, debugging, firebug

How can I find the specific code that's causing a web page to auto-refresh?

I've looked through the source for an HTML meta-refresh, to no avail. I also can't find any Javascript "reload" in the main page, leading me to think it's perhaps externally loaded through a link javascript file.

How would a "pro" track this down, like through Firebug (or other debugger)?

Note:

I'm more interested in the process of being able to debug and track down something like this, rather than a "catch-all" solution that will stop it cold (such as disabling the Firefox-wide ability for pages to auto-refresh themselves).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely in a javascript file. Go through them looking for the below:

1) Look for anything that can be used to change the URL/location, redirect, or cause browser to go back:

```
window.location.href
window.history.back(-1)
window.navigate(”example.html”);
self.location=”top.htm”;
top.location=”error.jsp”;
```

2) Look for timers such as:

```
setTimeout()
setInterval()
```

3) Look for broken selectors. You may have click event handlers attached to whole DIVs, or even the whole document by accident.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to set a breakpoint for a general refresh/browser reload, rather than having to scour through a list of Javascript files for various functions?

Answer (score 1):

There is **no** straightway to find the source of the refresh in javascript. Try @Steve Papa's tips on your code.Incase you want to prevent the refresh and see in the console if you can find any useful info.

To stop the refresh, use **onbeforeunload event**. The event object passed to the event has lot of info, but I couldnt find anything which points to the trigger. Add a breakpoint on closeIt(e), and look for clues in global variables or call stack(which i dont think will be of much use here).

```
function closeIt(){
      return "Any string value here forces a dialog box to \n" + 
     "appear before closing the window.";
}
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
 closeIt(e); //add a breakpoint here.
}
setTimeout(function(){location.reload()},2000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gjuhm/4/

Comment: Thanks. So there's not really any way to set a "generic" breakpoint on the browser refresh/reload, and then back-trace to see what function (and which external Javascript file) did it?